How can we avoid conflicts and duplicate commits in GitLab merge requests during successive merges from feature branches to recette, preprod and main?
Context: We are a team of developers working on the same project.
For this project, we have three static branches:
main
preprod
recette
When starting new development, we create a branch from main. (git checkout main, git pull, git checkout -b "new-branch") This new branch is named "feature/epic-ticket-number-subject".
Our merges are not done via the command line but through GitLab using merge requests.
When a development is completed, it is merged into recette. (feature --- merge ---> recette). If the development is validated in recette, it is merged into preprod. (feature --- merge ---> preprod). If the development is validated in preprod, it is merged into main. (feature --- merge ---> main).
If the development is not validated, modifications are added, and we merge the dev branch again into recette/preprod/main.
We doesn't use git flow, but if it's the solution we are aware to use it.
Issues:
When we try to rebase recette or preprod onto main, we encounter conflicts.
In our merge requests, GitLab displays commits and changes that are already present in the branch targeted by the merge.
We tried to rebase recette from main, after we haved merge feature into recette and main but we have conflict.
We expected to have a good workflow without conflict.
